# ASP.NET MVC 2 - AntiXSS vs Built In MVC Encoding

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2, antixsslibrary

Now that MVC has introduced HTML Encoding via

```
<%: blah %>
```

is there still value in using

```
<%= AntiXSS.HTMLEncode(blah) %>
```

instead?

For Example: My application will take all content in (including JavaScript) and store it in it's raw state in the database.  I was planning on simply **outputting** everything using something like `<%: model.Name %>` and relying on the MVC "stuff" to do the encoding for me.

Is that method secure enough to rely on for AntiXSS, or do I need to explicitly use the AntiXSS Library?  If I need to use the AntiXSS Library, can I ask why wouldn't that kind of thing be already built into MVC?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't think there's any real difference, but if you're really that concerned, you can use the AntiXss library as the default encoder for asp.net, as described in [this article](http://haacked.com/archive/2010/04/06/using-antixss-as-the-default-encoder-for-asp-net.aspx).

Comment: Hey that's a great article.  Makes a whole heck of a lot of sense.

Comment: Sorry, couldn't accept so soon, and by the time I could, I had forgotten about it. You can thank @Alfred for bringing the question back to the top of my list so that I was reminded to accept.

Answer (score 1):

<%: only encodes with [HTML encoding](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/04/06/new-lt-gt-syntax-for-html-encoding-output-in-asp-net-4-and-asp-net-mvc-2.aspx). If you're outputting to HTML attributes, Javascript or any space where the HTML body rules apply then you will still need to select the encoding method manually.

Answer (score 1):

Per Phil Haack's article: [Using AntiXss as the Default Encoder for ASP.NET](http://haacked.com/archive/2010/04/06/using-antixss-as-the-default-encoder-for-asp-net.aspx)  in ASP.NET 4 (including MVC), you can override the default HTML encoder to use the AntiXSS encoder.

Reasons against "AntiXSS.HTMLEncode"
1) The shorthand is easier to code
2) Calling the helper method (<%:%>/@:/HttpUtility.HtmlEncode/Server.HtmlEncode/etc.) and injecting the encoder implementation makes your code more maintainable vs. the specific AntiXSS implementation.

However, I believe "AntiXSS.HTMLEncode" is the only option for .NET versions < 4